# Can not send a ajax request from a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ujs

I am trying to send a ajax request from a form tag, but no XHR request is sent. If I do the same from a link everything works perfectly.

Here's the view from which I can send the request either from a link or a form:

```
<div id="request_test">
   <%= link_to "test", explorer_test_path(:format => :js), :remote => true %>
   <%= form_tag explorer_test_path(:format => :js), :id => "testform", :remote => true, :method => :get do %>
      <%= submit_tag "Send test request"%>
   <% end %>
</div>
<div id="response_test"></div>
```

In my controller I then check if it is a XHR request or not and then render the javascript responding to the ajax request:

```
def test
  if request.xhr?
    logger.debug "xhr"
  else
    logger.debug "not xhr"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

My test.js.erb is very simple:

```
$("#response_test").html("<b>hi</b>");
```

The result is that if I click the link I get the behavior I am looking for, ie that the response_test div reads "hi". If I submit the form I simply get the javascript in test.js.erb written out as a string and the server log telling me that the form didn't submit a XHR request. If i debug the whole thing in firebug I get the same result, the link sends an ajax request, the submitted form does not. In both cases my console tells me that the server is processing the request as JS, so it shouldn't be any data-type problem.

Running Rails 3.0.4 with jquery UJS.

Thankful for any hints to what the problem might be, I have tried to figure this out for quite some time now but since I am relatively new to Rails I suspect that I am missing something basic.

UPDATE: Adding the following javascript from (http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-jquery-ujs-now-interactive/) fixes the problem, which suggests that the :remote => true on my form tag isn't found or interpreted correctly by the jquery ujs. I see this as a workaround more than a permanent fix so if anybody have any idea of what is wrong in my original code I would be very grateful.

```
$('#testform').live('submit', function(e) {
  $.rails.handleRemote( $(this) );
  e.preventDefault();
});
```